# How to test a Bitbucket branch code before merging to master?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket account and there are multiple branches in it. When I am developing any new feature, I will create a branch from master and then start my new feature eg. "Feature A" branch.

Now when I am done with my new feature then I commit and push the changed files to Bitbucket in my separate branch "Feature A".

Is it possible to test particular "Feature A" branch? If yes then how can I access it in browser url?

Comment: The bigger question is, how were in a position to push your feature branch without first testing it locally?  Typically you would test your branch locally before you even consider pushing it to the remote.  Maybe tell us what your build setup is here.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it locally. But can I test it again after build in bitbucket branch? Because QA team wants to test first in branch after that I can merge it to master.

Comment: There are tools out there for dealing with this, e.g. Jenkins or TeamCity.  Basically, it shouldn't be your job to worry about testing/QA concerns.  Let your QA team deal with this.  Your responsibility is to make sure that whatever features you push have been well tested locally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in our work place I have to also test it first in loaclly and then in branch code and then QA will test it. If you have any helping links of jetkins or teamcity can you please forward me to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why Bitbucket has [Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/build-test-and-deploy-with-pipelines-792496469.html).